# Copying schema and data using SqlServer SMO in C# within a transaction scope

Tags: c#-4.0, smo

I have a requirement to copy a database in C# code. for this purpose, i have used the Sql Server SMO objects and tested it initially in a separate piece of code. That was working fine. However, when i am integrating the code with the existing functionality that is already wrapped up in a transaction scope, i was not able to execute the code inside the existing transaction scope.

Hence, i just created an inner transaction scope that had the transactionscope option as suppress so that this inner transaction scope will not be part of the outer scope. When i tried again, i get the transaction aborted exception.

Kindly suggest or refer me to using the database copy functionality within a transaction scope.